# I want to debug phantomJS using a breakpoint

Tags: phantomjs

I'm using phantomjs, but when I only open a specified web page, the following error appeared.

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: CollectGarbage

  undefined:1
  :0 in openUrl
  phantomjs://platform/webpage.js:291 in open
  phantomjs://code/memory_test.js:77
  phantomjs://code/memory_test.js:94
```

But I have inspected the my code for a long time, I do not know what is the cause.

So I try to debug the core source of phantomJS, but because I write a 'printf' or 'console.log' one by one, I'm so tired, so I want to set a breakpoint on the core source of phantomJS.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See remote debugging capabilities: http://phantomjs.org/troubleshooting.html#remote-debugging
(too musch information one the page to copy here)